# Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined CompileError: Begins at CSS selector .invert-color

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I have a project which works fine when I run `npm start`  but fails with this error when I run `npm run build` or `yarn build`

```
Failed to compile.

Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
CompileError: Begins at CSS selector .invert-color .form-checkbox input:checked,.invert-color .form-radio input:checked


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! open-react-template@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the open-react-template@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
...
```

Comment: You have applied toLowerCase on undefined or null value. Just check like : var lowerCase=(varA||"").toLowerCase();

Comment: Even when I search toLowerCase in the whole project I don't find it

Comment: Can you see what is happening around those indicated CSS selectors? Seems that is near the end of the trail. Is this the entire error? Is there any supplemental detail, like a sort of stacktrace into the file the error thrown in?

Comment: is this github issue helpful? https://github.com/cruip/open-react-template/issues/34

Comment: Yes, it was help full, I downgraded all the packages to the last working versions. I to find the actual package causing the issue I have to upgrade them one by one but I havent.

Comment: I had similar problem and fixed it by downgrading react-scripts version from 4.0.0 to 3.3.0